# Capture and Update Lidar Scan Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sensors, lidar

I want to get a Hokuyo UBG-04LX-F01 lidar to scan and read range data to matlab. My code only returns data for one scan, can someone provide help on how I can get the code to continuously return scan data (continuously update as the lidar scans). The code is for matlab. Thanks.

```
%This is the function to capture and display scan data
%It displays range data for one scan for 682 steps

function [rangescan] = CaptureData(Urg_device)

proceed=0;
while (proceed==0)
    fprintf(Urg_device, 'GD0044072500\n');
    pause(0.1);
    data = fscanf(Urg_device);

    if numel(data) == 2134
        proceed = 1;
    end 
end

i = find(data == data(13));
rangedata = data(i(3)+1:end-1);
onlyrangedata = [];
for j=0:31
    onlyrangedata((64*j)+1:(64*j)+64) = rangedata( 1+(66*j):64+(66*j));
end

j=0;
for i=1:floor(numel(onlyrangedata)/3)
    encodeddist(i,:)=[onlyrangedata((3*j)+1) onlyrangedata((3*j)+2) onlyrangedata((3*j)+3)];      
    j=j+1;
end
for k=1:size(encodeddist,1)
    rangescan(k)=decodeSCIP(encodeddist(k,:));
end

end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
This function decodes the data, works for 2 or 3 bit character encoding

function rangeval=decodeSCIP(rangeenc)
% Check for 2 or 3 Character Encoding
if rangeenc(1)=='0' && rangeenc(2)=='0' && rangeenc(3)=='0'
    rangeval=0;
    return;
end
if rangeenc(1)=='0'
    dig1=((rangeenc(2)-'!')+33);
    dig2=((rangeenc(3)-'!')+33);
    dig1sub=dig1-48;
    dig2sub=dig2-48;
    dig1bin=dec2bin(dig1sub,6);
    dig2bin=dec2bin(dig2sub,6);
    rangeval=bin2dec([dig1bin dig2bin]);
    return;
else
    dig1=((rangeenc(1)-'!')+33);
    dig2=((rangeenc(2)-'!')+33);
    dig3=((rangeenc(3)-'!')+33);
    dig1sub=dig1-48;
    dig2sub=dig2-48;
    dig3sub=dig3-48;
    dig1bin=dec2bin(dig1sub,6);
    dig2bin=dec2bin(dig2sub,6);
    dig3bin=dec2bin(dig3sub,6);
    rangeval=bin2dec([dig1bin dig2bin dig3bin]);
    return;

end

end
```

Comment: The initial while loop seems to be a very unsafe way to receive data. Doing this multiple times, at some point you will end up with 1000 bytes from the previous message and 1134 bytes from the following message, resulting in garbage being decoded. For continuous reading I recommend to switch to [callback functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/bytesavailablefcn.html)